# When nginx reports about limiting requests, what do theese numbers mean?

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting, net

When you setup nginx with `limit_req` [directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req), it logs excessive requests like

```
2019/10/30 17:41:36 [error] 10775#10775: *195997 limiting requests, excess: 10.210 by zone "zone_name" ...
```

I wonder, what means 10.210 here?
I suppose, that 10 is a burst size, defined in `limit_req` as `burst=10`, but what is 210 here?

Comment: IDK but maybe it's the burst size to three decimal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dzone.com/articles/nginx-rate-limiting states this is:

> Number of requests per millisecond over the configured rate that this request represents.

Comment: This should read `requests per second` (not millisecond).

Comment: Sure? NGINX internally calculates it down to miliseconds as the docu says: https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/ 

"[...]NGINX actually tracks requests at millisecond granularity[...]"